# May site A or B get banned/penalized if from site A I use window.open to site B?

Tags: seo, javascript, advertising

As many advertising systems open popups, I was wondering what if from my site A I make (randomly, I mean not every time) a `window.open(B)`?

Could one of the sites get banned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indirectly, **yes**. Users will spend less time on your website because you have annoying popup advertising. They will return to the search page with the same query looking for another source, and that's bad for your search position.

Comment: I would probably only Do it if the user spent more than 30 seconds or so.. and I could also Do this for non search engine visitors

Answer (score 0):

No absolutely non of these sites will get banned or penalized.

Comment: hi! thanks for answering, how confident are you about this?

Comment: it did, google views dropped like 50%